# Can I get the current app in foreground on current android versions?

Tags: android, xamarin

With the current versions of Android: Is there still a way to get any hint which application is currently in the foreground (e.g. package name)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't query this information in any Android version, but if you make an [accessibility service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService), you will be notified every time any window is displayed in the foreground, and will be able to determine what package it belongs to.

Note, the user would have to enable your service in settings for this to work, and your app may not be accepted to Google Play store if you abuse this feature.